# Right way to add Managed Identity to Azure service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric, azure-managed-identity, azure-vm-scale-set

Since there is no straight forward way to add Managed Identity directly to the Azure service fabric, thinking of adding Managed Identity instead to the Azure VM Scaleset Instance which is in turn managed by the intended Azure service fabric instance. So that the Service Fabric applications (which eventually get deployed to those VMs of the Azure VM Scaleset Instance) can leverage Managed Identity provisioned for the Azure VM Scale set Instance, to access other Azure resources like Azure Key vault etc.

Is this right way of creating managed identity for the Azure service fabric applications? (or) is there any way of enabling managed identity for the Azure service fabric using Powershell or Azure portal?

Is there any way to restrict, Managed Identity only to certain application in Azure service fabric cluster but to not all applications?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this right way of creating managed identity for the Azure service fabric applications? (or) is there any way of enabling managed identity for the Azure service fabric using Powershell or Azure portal?

Yes, it should be the right way, you could leverage the MSI(managed identity) of VMSS to access the azure resources.
The doc also mentions the same way - [Authenticate Service Fabric applications to Azure Resources using Managed Service Identity (MSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-best-practices-security#authenticate-service-fabric-applications-to-azure-resources-using-managed-service-identity-msi), it provides a way of ARM template to enable the MSI.

To enable the MSI of VMSS via powershell or portal, you could refer to

- [Configure managed identities for Azure resources on virtual machine scale sets using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-powershell-windows-vmss)
- [Configure managed identities for Azure resources on a virtual machine scale set (VMSS) using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vmss)

**Note:** Before you use the MSI to access Azure resources, you need to [grant the correct RBAC roles to the MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) at the resource scope. For Azure keyvault, you need to [add the MSI to the access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal).

> Is there any way to restrict, Managed Identity only to certain application in Azure service fabric cluster but to not all applications?

No, you can't. When the MSI is enabled for the VMSS, it will apply to all the applications in the VMSS.

If you want to restrict the MSI only to a certain application, you may need to deploy Service Fabric application with [system-assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-deploy-service-fabric-application-system-assigned-managed-identity) or [User-Assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-deploy-service-fabric-application-user-assigned-managed-identity) managed identity, use the MSI of application instead of VMSS, make sure [enable the Managed Identity Token Service on the cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-existing-cluster-enable-managed-identity-token-service) firstly.

Comment: Thanks @Joy Wang, there is another MS link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-existing-cluster-enable-managed-identity-token-service#enable-managed-identity-token-service-in-an-existing-cluster says about enabling managed identity on SF cluster itself instead of VMSS level. What is the difference between enabling managed identity on SF cluster versus on the VMSS? When to choose which one out of these possibilities (or) they are there to serve different purpose?

Comment: @AzEnthu To enable the managed identity token service is in order to use MSI of application, if you use MSI of application, the MSI is just can be available in application, if you use MSI of VMSS, the MSI can be available in all the applications in the VMSS.

Comment: The above answer helps. Is enabling MSI for SF application, possible only via ARM? or is it possible via Powershell or Azure portal. We are doing SF deployment using Octopus, if that is the case wondering how to change "Application template" to include the identity property to it?

Comment: @AzEnthu Yes, it is only available via ARM template, anyway you need to enable Managed Identity Token Service on the cluster via [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-existing-cluster-enable-managed-identity-token-service#enable-managed-identity-token-service-in-an-existing-cluster) in the template, then use the application template, the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-deploy-service-fabric-application-user-assigned-managed-identity#application-template) includes the identity property.

Comment: @ Joy Wang, with ARM template as the only option available to enable MSI for SF applications, makes it harder to implement. Considering that I believe enabling MSI for VMSS would be more straight forward & this approach would still keep the security aspects intact. Do you see any problem or disadvantage in enabling MSI for VMSS rather than on SF applications?

Comment: @AzEnthu No, there are just some differences as I mentioned above, feel free to use it.